# Cross-platform globbing in Perl

Tags: perl, cross-platform, glob

In my cross-platform Perl application, I use `File::HomeDir` and `File::Spec` for constructing platform-independent paths. How to do cross-platform globbing?

Comment: You seem to imply that globbing was restricted to a specific platform? Can you elaborate a bit?

Comment: @Ingo: The difference between slashes and backslashes made me wary. Also, perhaps different platforms interpret wildcards and `.`/`..` results differently. If there's nothing to worry about, that would be a fine answer.

Comment: At least you do not have to worry about the slash vs. backslash thing. I don't know how the myth that windows filenames must use slashes is still surviving ....

Answer (score 2):

You may want to look at core [File::Glob](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Glob.html) module. It has quote good notes on various specifics in documentation and it should be quite cross-platform.